# Enviar petición http con POST y probarlo en Postman

Tags: php, webservice, http-post

Tengo el siguiente código php que recibe la variable `coordenadas` enviada desde una app iOS:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['coordenadas'])) {

    $to = "reportes@midomimio.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = "info@test.com"; // this is the sender's Email address
    $coordenadas = $_POST['coordenadas'];
    $subject = "Reporte";
    $message = "Localización:" . $coordenadas;

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    $resultados = Array("error" => "1","mensaje" => "Se envio coordenadas:".$coordenadas);

} else {

    $resultados = Array("error" => "1","mensaje" => "Acceso denegado");
}

echo json_encode($resultados);
?>
```

Cuando envío la petición desde mi app funciona perfectamente (envía un correo con la variable `coordenadas`)

Pero si lo pruebo con POSTMAN, siempre me devuelve:

```
{
error: "1",
mensaje: "Acceso denegado"
}
```

NO entiendo si desde que le estoy pasando la variable  `coordenadas` en postman me devuelve acceso denegado como si el contenido de la variable no existiera.

Agradeceré alguna ayuda al respecto.[image: Resultado en postman]

Comment: debes usar es body, cuando usas params lo agrega al GET

Comment: Si el método es POST no deberías enviarlo desde la URL, como te dice @JackNavaRow, tienes que usar la pestaña BODY

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas. Use la pestaña BODY y dentro de esta marque la opción `x-www-form-urlencoded` y ahí puse el parámetro y funcionó. Gracias.